# How to use Truffle with Solidity 0.4

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

I just tried to set up a truffle project and tried to compile a contract I have already written.

When I do so I get the following error message:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solidity-parser/index.js:39
      throw e;
      ^
SyntaxError: Expected "contract", "import", "library", comment, end of input, end of line or whitespace but "p" found. Line: 1, Column: 1
    at peg$buildException (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solidity-parser/build/imports_parser.js:423:14)
    at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solidity-parser/build/imports_parser.js:3355:13)
    at Object.module.exports.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solidity-parser/index.js:34:23)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/profiler.js:134:36
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

The first line the compiler is complaining about is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
```

As far as I know there is no way I could let that line out. Is there a solution that lets me use Truffle with the most recent version of solidity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your contract? Would help if you could post it here

Comment: I think it will work without that pragma line, please try once without that line.

Comment: It does not work without it. If I use Solidity 0.4 the compiler complains about the _;

Comment: What does `solc --version` give? If I use v0.3.6, I get the same error on the `pragma` line.

Comment: My solc was still 0.3 but now i updated it to Version: 0.4.1-develop.2016.09.09+commit.79867f4.Linux.g++
and still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added support solidity 0.4.x and released a new version of Truffle. You can read the announcement here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/574rvr/truffle_v210_now_with_solc_04x_support/

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, so I asked on Truffle's Gitter channel, and this is the answer I received:

> Truffle will not support solc 0.4.x until Truffle 3.0 is released, as significant changes to Truffle are required.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I can't know without the code for context, but I would bet that this is in a function modifier and the line above it is `_`.

In Solidity >= 0.4, the `_` must have a semicolon after it.

i.e. `_;`

You should also add the suggested pragma line at the top of your files, just so it stops complaining.

See the [Release notes](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.0) for details

Comment: Exactly that's the problem. My code *is* written in Solidity 0.4 and I have the _; in the modifiers. The compiler complains that my code begins with "pragma" and not with "contract" or "library"

Comment: Oh, I see. I think Truffle just compiles using your local solc, so as long as that's up to date, I don't know why it would complain

Comment: As I have already mentioned above: My solc was still 0.3 but now i updated it to Version: 0.4.1-develop.2016.09.09+commit.79867f4.Linux.g++ and still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The shortest working solution is using Browser Solidity ( https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ ) and just tell it to use Solidity 0.3.6, then things will work out again in truffle.

I'm struggling under the same problem, and **eventually**, there is a workaround - I havn't tried it myself yet:

1. compile and deploy your contract "the hard way" via solidity and geth.
2. run `truffle migrate` and `truffle build` on your truffle project without the `pragma solidity ^0.4.0;` in your contract
3. take the adress of your "manually deployed" contract, open the app.js built by truffle under /build/app.js, find `Contract.all_networks` and change the address to the of your manually deployed contract.

This way you possibly could trick your truffle build to use the previously well compiled contract. Absolutely no warranty, maybe someone with deeper understanding of all this can tell, if this is completely nonesense or a viable solution.

PS: compiling and deploying the hard way: 
1. `$ sudo apt-get install -y solc`
2. Remove all line breaks from your contract code (online tools might help)
3. In `geth`: `> var myContractSource = *paste contract source without linebreaks here*`
4. `> var myContractCompiled = eth.compile.solidity(myContractSource)`
5. > `var myContract = eth.contract(myContractCompiled.theContractNameInTheSolidityCode.info.abiDefinition);`
6. again without linebreaks and with **mining turned on:**

```
var myContractTransaction = myContract.new({
    from: eth.coinbase, 
    data: myContractCompiled.theContractNameInTheSolidityCode.code, 
    value: 1000000000000000000,
    gas: 1000000
  },
  function(err, contract) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err); 
      } else {
        console.log(contract); 
        console.log(contract.address);
      }
});
```

the last returned address is the address of your contract.

PPS: Again, I'm not sure, but maybe in the bespoke `app.js` you might also have to replace the `unlinked_binary` (under contract.all_networks) with what you find as `code:` when doing just `> myContractCompiled` in geth after defining this var. those values look somehow related to the identification of contracts to me.

I hope I could be of help. Let's wait for the update of truffle..