# development environment for solidity 0.4

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is there any development environment currently supporting solidity 0.4+? Apparently [Truffle doesn't support it yet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/how-to-use-truffle-with-solidity-0-4), Mix IDE appears to have been discontinued, [ether.camp is offline](https://live.ether.camp/). I haven't tried Dapple or Embark so I can't say anything about those. Has anyone already switched to the new solidity version and if so what are they using to develop and test contracts?

Comment: In solidity 0.4 Documentation they refer to Dapple, so I think It's ok.
As soon as possible I will try with Dapple.

Comment: Dapple is working on a new version with 0.4 support, same for truffle. If you can't wait, Dapple (and proably truffle) have develop branches that you can build from source